# Email is not attaching the mail

Tags: linux

I have the following script in linux. Emails are getting sent but attachment is not getting attached.Even if I give the correct path of the error file it doesn't work. Please help

Thanks

```
ERROR_FILE="error1.txt"

 SEND_EMAIL()
       {
            email_recipient=xyz@company.com
           ( echo "From: abc@company.com"
             echo "To: "${email_recipient}""
              echo "Subject: Some errors are on this process check log for  
                    more details"
                    cat ${ERROR_FILE} ) | /usr/lib/sendmail -i -t 
                    2> /dev/null
         }

                    SEND_EMAIL
```

Comment: Does the script output any errors? If you redirect to a file (`> message.txt`) instead of piping to `sendmail`, do you see the same thing?